# Angular pattern doesn't work

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have a problem with ng-pattern.

```js
function formCtrl($scope){}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app ng-controller="formCtrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <input ng-model="sign_username"ng-minlength="6" ng-maxlength="15" ng-pattern="/[\p{L}0-9]+$/u" required>
  </form>
  {{myForm.$valid}}
</div>
```

ng-minlength and ng-maxlength work correctly but when I use special characters ng-pattern still is positive.

I want to check if field contains only letters (unicode) and digits.

Comment: `\p{L}` is not supported by JS regex.

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[\p{L}0-9]+$/: Invalid escape
    at <anonymous>:1:1